# Gerrit prolog rule - setting accumulative voting adequately

Tags: linux, github, prolog, gerrit

I want to create the following rule:

- The patch will become in submittable only there is 3 votes or more with +1, but THERE SHOULD NOT BE a vote with +2, only votes with +1 will be considered for this criterion.

The rule that i have is:

```
% rule      : 1+1+1=2 Code-Review                                       
% rationale : introduce accumulative voting to determine if a change    
%             is submittable or not and make the change submittable        
%             if the total score is 3 or higher.                                                                                                                                                                   

sum_list([], 0).                                                        
sum_list([H | Rest], Sum) :- sum_list(Rest,Tmp), Sum is H + Tmp.        

add_category_min_score(In, Category, Min,  P) :-                        
    findall(X, gerrit:commit_label(label(Category,X),R),Z),             
    sum_list(Z, Sum),                                                   
    Sum >= Min, !,                                                      
    gerrit:commit_label(label(Category, V), U),                         
    V >= 1,                                                             
    !,                                                                  
    P = [label(Category,ok(U)) | In].                                   

add_category_min_score(In, Category,Min,P) :-                           
    P = [label(Category,need(Min)) | In].                               

submit_rule(S) :-                                                       
    gerrit:default_submit(X),                                           
    X =.. [submit | Ls],                                                
    gerrit:remove_label(Ls,label('Code-Review',_),NoCR),                
    add_category_min_score(NoCR,'Code-Review', 3, Labels),              
    S =.. [submit | Labels].
```

this rule does not works at all, the problem is with the +2 vote.
How can i rework this rule in order to works as i want?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have min three reviewers that can add +1 and +2 is not allowed.

What if you remove developers rights to give +2 from project config and use prolog     cookbook example 13 with little modifications?

```
submit_rule(submit(CR)) :-
  sum(3, 'Code-Review', CR),
  % gerrit:max_with_block(-1, 1, 'Verified', V).

% Sum the votes in a category. Uses a helper function score/2
% to select out only the score values the given category.
sum(VotesNeeded, Category, label(Category, ok(_))) :-
  findall(Score, score(Category, Score), All),
  sum_list(All, Sum),
  Sum >= VotesNeeded,
  !.
sum(VotesNeeded, Category, label(Category, need(VotesNeeded))).

score(Category, Score) :-
  gerrit:commit_label(label(Category, Score), User).

% Simple Prolog routine to sum a list of integers.
sum_list(List, Sum)   :- sum_list(List, 0, Sum).
sum_list([X|T], Y, S) :- Z is X + Y, sum_list(T, Z, S).
sum_list([], S, S).
```